# Is it just of me to use an existing comment as the basis for my answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I have recently seen a trend of some detailed comments on the question. Some of these comments have legitimate answers. Is it correct of me to take the information provided through comments, and some of my own knowledge to answer a question? I feel that it is ok because the comments could easily be transformed into an answer in which the OP could see.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is fine, but do attribute the source of the information.

Note that if you were to just copy a comment ad verbatim, I'd ask the author of the comment to do so first. But given that you add your own content as well, I'd say you're fine.